# SQL Server Export fails on DateTime2 => PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, datetime2

I am trying to export number databases from MS SQL to PostgreSQL.

Unfortunately SQL Server Export tool fails to work with DateTime2 type columns.

Everytime I am getting:

> Error 0xc020844b: Data Flow Task 1: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Char[]'.

I have tried date, time without time zone, timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time zone and also tried text.

I don't have any columns with DateTime so cannot check if that would work.

Not sure why it says that it is casting from DateTime to Char[], but I guess it is an internal error from the export tool

Anyone played with SQL Management Studio and Export tool ?

Perhaps there is something better to export large number of tables (open source for windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Microsoft SQL Export/Import tool.

It worked fine using other tool, and database was successfully exported.